# Grafana - Azure Application Insights - Filter on "message" column

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, grafana, azure-monitoring

I would like to filter on the 'message' column using the **Application Insights** datasource, but it seems like I can filter on everything but the 'message' column..?

**Application Insights**

[image]

**Working Query**

[image]

**Failing Query**

[image]

Clicking on the "Group By" select shows all the columns except the message column..

### How do I filter on message column with equal/contains?

*I apologize in advance for the lack of skills in grafana, rookie here ;)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By enabling 'edit mode' for query, I was able to filter on message.

[image]

[image]

Same query language as application insights.

[image]